# Помогите решить задачу на C++ 1 курс

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
int a, b, c, d, q;
setlocale(0, "rus");

cout « "введите первое число \n";
cin» a;
cout « "введите второе число\n ";
cin » b;
cout « "введите третье число\n ";
cin » c;
cout « "введите четвертое число\n ";
cin » d;
cout « "введите пятое число\n ";
cin » q;
if (a < 10 && b < 10 && c < 10 && d < 10 && q < 10);
cout « b;
cout « c;
cout « a;
cout « q;
cout « d;
```

Comment: `if (a < 10 && b < 10 && c < 10 && d < 10 && q < 10);` - дословно означает "проверить, что и a меньше 10, и b ... , и независимо от результата сравнения - ничего не делать.

Comment: И как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ладно, раз уж вы старались :)

```
int main()
{
    int a[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Введите число N " << (i+1) << ": ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] < 10) cout << a[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое исправление:

```
if (a < 10)
    cout << a;
if (b < 10)
    cout << b;
//  ... итд.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//if (a < 10 && b < 10 && c < 10 && d < 10 && q < 10) - Ця перевірка спрацює лише тоді коли всі числа менші 10

    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        int a, b, c, d, q;
         
        //Запрошуємо числа в користувача
        std::cout << "Enter num \n";
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << "Enter num \n ";
        std::cin >> b;
        std::cout << "Enter num \n ";
        std::cin >> c;
        std::cout << "Enter num \n ";
        std::cin >> d;
        std::cout << "Enter num\n ";
        std::cin >> q;
    
        //Виводи числа менші за 10
        if (c < 10) 
        {
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
        }
    
        if (b < 10)
        {
            std::cout << b << std::endl;
        }
    
        if (a < 10)
        {
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
    
        if (d < 10)
        {
            std::cout << d << std::endl;
        }
    
        if (q < 10)
        {
            std::cout << q << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]